# "make dependencies" on Mac gives --> "make: lsb_release: Command not found" error

Tags: macos, makefile, terminal, zsh, gnu-make

```
$ make dependencies
```

in my terminal on Mac gives

```
make: lsb_release: Command not found
```

Here is the full message:

```
make: lsb_release: Command not found
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
/bin/bash: md5sum: command not found
mldb/ext/tinyxml2//tinyxml2.mk:1: *** hash_command1 didnt set variable g++_-fPIC_-m64_-fno-omit-frame-pointer_-msse3_-msse4.2_-Imldb_-Wall_-Werror_-Wno-sign-compare_-Woverloaded-virtual_-Wno-deprecated-declarations_-Wno-deprecated_-Winit-self_-Wno-unused-but-set-variable_-Wno-psabi_-Wno-unknown-pragmas_-pipe_-ggdb_-std_c++0x_-D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP_1_-D_GLIBCXX_USE_SCHED_YIELD_1_-fno-builtin-malloc_-fno-builtin-calloc_-fno-builtin-realloc_-fno-builtin-free_-o_build/x86_64/obj/mldb/ext/tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp.lo_-c_./mldb/ext/tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp_-MP_-MMD_-MF_build/x86_64/obj/mldb/ext/tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp.d_-MQ_build/x86_64/obj/mldb/ext/tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp.lo_-O3_-DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS_-DNDEBUG_hash.  Stop.
```

I have GNU Make 3.81 installed. Also, I did:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer


$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I am on a Mac OS X. It could be linked to zsh since I installed it not too long ago and I believe that all my xcode related tools worked just fine before.

Thanks for any help or indication that can point me in the right direction to fix this.

**Update**
c++ code that I was trying to build is for ubuntu 14

Answer (score 7):

`lsb_release` is a command that runs on Linux only: the "LSB" stands for "Linux Standard Base" and this refers to a standard baseline set of tools and libraries that Linux distributions can elect to support.

Your makefile should not be invoking that command, since it's not portable to OS X.  I'd say that whatever code you're trying to build is not ported to OS X and will only build on Linux.  But since you didn't provide any other details, we can't say for sure.

Comment: I was trying to build code that I found on github. I contacted the team that developed it and you are right. The code is for Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!